# Displaying List of items within an arraylist within a JSP

Tags: java, javascript, web-services, jsp

I am building a SOAP web service which allows the user to add/delete or list a bibliography list.

I have implemented the add method which adds a new list to the file and also saves it to a file in xml format. This method works with the soap web services but now I have to implement a list method which will allow me to display the item list within a jsp for starters. I am having trouble implementing any solution I have tried many but with no luck.

I have a class Reference with two sub classes Book and journal for now which are the two items the user can input. They are saved to a list in a separate class. For starters I just want to know how I can display the contents of the list on a jsp and later on integrate that with SOAP.

My knowledge with web development is quite low and I am learning as I go but I need some help understanding how to complete this task. any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Adrian

Answer (score 0):

This is how I display items in an `ArrayList` on my jsp page:

```
<table>
<c:forEach var="comp" items="${complains}" >
<tr>
<td>${comp["complain"]}</td>
<td>${comp["status"]}</td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
```

Here `complains` is name of the `ArrayList` object that I set using:

```
ArrayList<ComplainVO> mylist = getMyArrayList();
request.setAttribute("complains", mylist);
```